# Entity Framework case statement

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am working on getting this select into a EF, In the model `IsGroupAdmin` is a boolean. So I check if its null using `== null` and then check it is `< 0` and then `>=0`. I am getting runtime error about missing `}` but I think its something else.

SQL select:

```
[IsGroupAdmin] = (SELECT ISNULL((SELECT CASE WHEN g.MaxNumberCustomers < 0 THEN 0 
                  CASE WHEN g.MaxNumberCustomers >= 0 THEN x.IsGroupAdmin 
                  END
                 FROM [dbo].[CustomerGroupXref] x
                 JOIN dbo.[Group] g ON g.groupid = x.GroupId
                 WHERE CustomerId = 2488475 AND g.IsActive = 1 AND g.GroupId = sfd.GroupId), 1))
```

EF

```
IsGroupAdmin = (from cgx in db.CustomerGroupXrefs
                join ga in db.Groups on cgx.GroupId equals ga.GroupId
                where ga.IsActive == true && cgx.CustomerId == CustomerId
                select new
                       {
                           Name = (ga.MaxNumberCustomers == null) ?
                           ga.MaxNumberCustomers < 0 ? false :
                           ga.MaxNumberCustomers >= 0 ? cgx.IsGroupAdmin: 
                       }).FirstOrDefault()
```

Runtime error

[image]

Updated base on information

```
 IsGroupAdmin = (from cgx in db.CustomerGroupXrefs
                 join ga in db.Groups on cgx.GroupId equals ga.GroupId
                 where ga.IsActive == true 
                    && cgx.CustomerId == CustomerId
                    && ga.MaxNumberCustomers != null 
                    && ga.MaxNumberCustomers >= 0
                    && cgx.IsGroupAdmin ==true
                 select cgx.IsGroupAdmin)
                 .Any(),
```

Comment: It would help if share the full error

Comment: you have nested ternary operators that are a mild mess.  you need something after `cgx.IsGroupAdmin` on the second to last line

Comment: That looks like a compile time error, not a runtime error.

Comment: Oh something like this ga.MaxNumberCustomers >= 0 ? cgx.IsGroupAdmin.Value

Comment: The expression should probably be `ga.MaxNumberCustomers != null && ga.MaxNumberCustomers >= 0 && cgx.IsGroupAdmin` which is also easier to read IMO. I do not believe `ga.MaxNumberCustomers != null` is necessary if this is Linq to Entities but it can't hurt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression should probably be (guessing based on the code available):

```
ga.MaxNumberCustomers != null && ga.MaxNumberCustomers >= 0 && cgx.IsGroupAdmin
```

This is also easier to read IMO. I do not believe `ga.MaxNumberCustomers != null` is necessary if this is Linq to Entities but it can't hurt.

Comment: Just to make sure i understand I updated my post can you double check

Comment: @Jefferson - Yes, that is a perfectly valid way to use that expression.